# JQuery: Accordion style menu toggle

Tags: jquery, toggle

I'm trying to make a simple accordion style menu using divs:

```
<div class="subdomainLevel">
    Subdomain <a href="#" class="pageToggle">open/close</a>

    <div class="pageLevel">Page Level <a href="#" class="messageToggle">open/close</a>
        <div class="pageMessage">Message</div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="subdomainLevel">
    Subdomain <a href="#" class="pageToggle">open/close</a>

    <div class="pageLevel">Page Level <a href="#" class="messageToggle">open/close</a>
        <div class="pageMessage">Message</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

My jquery is as follows:

```
var page = $(".subdomainLevel").children(".pageLevel");
$(".pageToggle").click(function () {
    $(page).slideToggle("fast");
});
```

How can I make my JQuery reusable so that when I click on my "open/close" link, the link only controls the child of that div and not the other divs on the page with the same class.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of:

```
 $(page).slideToggle("fast");
```

use:

```
$(this).siblings('.pageLevel').slideToggle("fast");
```

example at:

http://jsfiddle.net/2CEmx/

**Edit:**
so you don't really need this line at all:

```
var page = $(".subdomainLevel").children(".pageLevel");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(this).next(".pageLevel").slideToggle("fast");
```